# Storing object in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Here is a simple program. I am assigned to store the objects in an array. But as I am a beginner student so i dont know how to store objects in array. Could somebody please help me with this question?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MainExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    double length; 
    double width; 
    double price_per_sqyd;
    double price_for_padding; 
    double price_for_installation;
        String input; 
    double final_price; 
        boolean repeat = true;


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (repeat)
        {   


    System.out.println("\n" +"What is the length of the room?: ");
    length = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the width of the room?: ");
    width = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the price of the carpet per square yard?: ");
    price_per_sqyd = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the price for the padding?: ");
        price_for_padding = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the price of the installation?: ");
        price_for_installation = keyboard.nextDouble();


        keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println( "\n" + "Type 'yes' or 'no' if this is correct: ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        if ("yes".equals(input)) 
         repeat = true; 
        else 
         repeat = false; 

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to store?

Comment: Use `Object[] objArray = new Object[length]`

Comment: what is that you want to store in an object array, if your code doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to create a class to hold the attributes like so. Create a constructor to initialize these values.

```
public class Room{
     double length; 
   double width; 
    double price_per_sqyd;
    double price_for_padding; 
    double price_for_installation;
    String input; 
    double final_price; 
    boolean repeat = true;

}
```

then in your main method/driver class create an array with the type of this class and store relevant objects.

```
Room arr=new Room[100];
 int count=0;
     while (repeat)
        {   


    System.out.println("\n" +"What is the length of the room?: ");
    length = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the width of the room?: ");
    width = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the price of the carpet per square yard?:      ");
    price_per_sqyd = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the price for the padding?: ");
        price_for_padding = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the price of the installation?: ");
    price_for_installation = keyboard.nextDouble();


        keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println( "\n" + "Type 'yes' or 'no' if this is correct: ");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
arr[count]=new Room(length,width,price1,price2,price3,price4);//call to the constructor
    if ("yes".equals(input)) 
     repeat = true; 
count++;
    else 
     repeat = false; 

    } 
}
```

Comment: @MohammedSohailEbrahim-   Sorry, but now I got another question.
Now that the objects are stored in array, i want to print the objects from array. For example, user enters (yes) and enters the size for many rooms but when the user enters (no) it stops. After the programs stops, I want to reprint all the things that the user entered in one line. 
I hope I clearly described the question.

Comment: hmm you might want to include a toString method within the object class. this merthod should cooncatenate all the data fields of the object and return it in whatever form you choose. after that its as simple as looping throught the array and printing the array[whatever index].toString(); let me know how that goes sorry i was away for a while

Comment: I brought some changes and now it prints the objects but it still gives error. Could you please check this out: System.out.println("Thank you!"; 
for (int j = 0; j < room.length-1; j++) {
 System.out.println("Length = " + room[j].getLength()); System.out.println("width = " + room[j].getWidth()); and etc

Answer (score 0):

Although not very elegant, a quick solution for this toy program would be to make a "Room" class with the various properties like "length", "width", "price_per_sqft" etc. Then you can set specific property of each room object and store the "room" objects in an array of "Room".

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to store in an array? The different `final_price` values?

Regardless, because you don't know how many times your loop will run, you probably need an ArrayList. You could create this by adding `ArrayList <Double> prices = new ArrayList <Double> ();`

Then, add a line at the end of your loop that stores the correct variable to the ArrayList. For example: `prices.add(final_price);`

If `final_price` is not what you are trying to store, then just replace it with the variable you do want to store.

Also, don't forget that if you do use an ArrayList, you will need the correct import statement at the top of your code: `import java.util.ArrayList;`